# Regular expression to add a string

Tags: regex

I have the string `src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9w6YSZ_o7rA"` where the URL could be anything, and I want to add `?autoplay=1` at the end, so I'll have:

```
src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9w6YSZ_o7rA?autoplay=1"
```

Could someone recommend a clean regex expression to use with JavaScript str.replace()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't require regex.

edit: updated to account for possible fragment (though It's n/a for youtube urls)

```
src = src.split('#');
src[0]+= (src[0].indexOf('?')>-1) ? '&' : '?';
src[0]+= 'autoplay=1';
src = src.join('#');
```

Comment: And just to be pedantic... what if the URL has a fragment? e.g. `www.site.com/page.html?foo=bar#fraggy`. Just sayin...

Comment: In general, good call. In practice, youtube urls shouldn't have a fragment on them. That's not to say they may not change that

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replace(/(.*)/,'$1?autoplay=1');
```

this should help you

Comment: this doesn't account for if there's already a query string present

Comment: @CrayonViolent sorry i didn't understand your doubt

Comment: your code won't work. What do you think will happen if `src='www.site.com/page.html?foo=bar` you will end up with `src='www.site.com/page.html?foo=bar?autoplay=1` when it should be appended with `&` since query string already exists

Comment: got the flaw in my approach